# Librato installation fail with "Error: Reading the config file failed!"

Tags: installation, collectd, librato

The "Easy install" isn't working, no data are sent to Librato
I followed step by instructions for "Advanced" and end up with this error :

Error: Reading the config file failed!
Read the logs for details.
not restarting due to configuration error

And nothing in /var/log/messages
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you contact support@librato.com? You can also contact support via [live chat](https://www.librato.com/docs/kb/faq/live_chat/#live-chat-support) in-app.

Comment: I didn't. I would if totlly stucked, but I finally managed to install it and I will post here the list of commands when I have 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To install librato on Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03, here is what worked for me :

If you tried your luck with "Easy install", first remove it as it is a collectd brought by Amazon and it will never work with Librato

> sudo yum remove collectd

Go to *integrations*, select *Amazon Linux* and then *Advanced*. There is nothing for 2018.03, so take the latest one wich is 2017.03. It workd for me.
Follow step 1 to 4 then type those 2 commands :

> sudo ldconfig
>
> sudo ln -svf /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.181.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib64/libjvm.so

The 1st one cleans stuff from collectd provided by Amazon and the second one is necessary because librato collectd plugins are using java and expects the library in a certain place.

Then you can go to step 5 :

> sudo service collectd restart

Hope this will save you some time!